# How can I add a ssh host key in a client programmatically?

Tags: ssh, unix, openssh

After installing a server, I want it to connect to a remote host and add its host key to ssh without asking for confirmation, inside a script. Can I do so by passing the expected fingerprint to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use [ssh-keyscan](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keyscan&sektion=1)

```
ssh-keyscan <Server_Hostname_or_ip_address> >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

more options [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/132970/can-i-automatically-add-a-new-host-to-known-hosts)

Comment: I guess there is no way to make a check on the fingerprint then...